# How many terms in a linear polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

> ***A linear polynomial can have a maximum of two terms.***

My textbook states this but I can find a linear polynomial of more than 2 terms.

Like $2x + \pi + \sqrt{2}$

Since there are infinite irrationals and we cannot simplify them by adding together then I can have polynomials of any type with as any terms as I like.

And if you say that constants can't be considered terms. Then it is also not the case :-

As $2x + 7$ is considered as a polynomial of 2 terms by the same book. I think it's the same in all books.

So is the statement that ***a polynomial can have a maximum of two terms.*** false?

Comment: No, $f=2x+a$, where $a$ counts as **one** term if it doesn't contain $x$. So $a=\pi+\sqrt{2}$ is the **constant term** (only One).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Alright, I have understood it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A term in a polynomial is defined to be a non-negative power power of $x$ (i.e., $1$ or $x$ or $x^2$ etc.) multiplied by a constant.

What you are running into is an issue of whether you are referring to terms in a polynomial or terms in a *representation* of a polynomial.

So the representation $2x+\pi+\sqrt{2}$ has 3 terms ($2x$, $\pi$, and $\sqrt{2}$), but the constant part, $\pi+\sqrt{2}$, is just a real number and so the polynomial $Ax+B$ really only has 2 terms: $Ax=2x$ is a term and $B=(\pi+\sqrt{2})$ is its other term.

You could think of this as the difference between unsimplified vs. simplified answers.

While I can represent a linear polynomial with as many terms as a like, a linear polynomial has at most two terms. For example: The representation $5x+4x+3x+2+1$ has 5 terms, but this polynomial simplifies to $12x+3$ and as a polynomial only has two terms.

Language isn't already used in a precise way. Another example, akin to what you're dealing with is someone might say the fraction $6/12$ has the numerator $6$. But a fraction doesn't have a numerator. More precisely, a *representation* of a fraction has a numerator. The fraction $6/12=1/2$. Is this fraction's numerator $6$ or $1$? On the other hand, the representation $6/12$ has numerator $6$ and the representation $1/2$ has numerator $1$.

Comment: It makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you define as term.

If one were to define it "naively" as number of occurring summands then this would not make a good definition, as
$$2x+4=x+x+1+1+2+0$$
and thus it's not clear if $2x+4$ would have $2$ or $5$ terms.

Here my best guess is that the number of terms is counted as usual: when the polynomial is represented canonically as
$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0$$
then the number of non-zero $a_i$ is the number of terms.

In particular a linear polynomial, being of the form
$$a_1x+a_0$$
can have at most two terms.

Comment: Okay, I have understood now.